# Project Maven Duplicated log4j.xml from dependency

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, maven, logging

I have a Maven project with some dependency from a major project. One of those dependency inserts a log4j.xml file into my final jar derived from the build. I had removed all the duplicated dependecies from my project and insert manually log4j (not derived from any other dependecy). But It haven't work, the other log4j file still imports
I wanna know how to stop importing this log4j.xml file and get only the log4j from the src/main/resources of the minor project.

I have just a log4j.xml in the resources and no other configuration file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<!-- ===================================================================== -->
<!-- Log4j Configuration -->
<!-- Created by Ant. Base file: log4j.xml.unparsed -->
<!-- ===================================================================== -->


<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/"
    debug="false">

    <!-- ================================= -->
    <!-- Preserve messages in a local file -->
    <!-- ================================= -->

    <!-- A size based rolling appender -->
    <appender name="FILEZEUS" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="log/Generate_Curve.log" />
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10MB" />
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="20" />
        <param name="Append" value="true" />
        <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <!-- The default pattern: Date Priority [Category] Message\n -->
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c] %m%n" />

            <!-- The full pattern: Date MS Priority [Category] (Thread:NDC) Message\n 
                <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5r %-5p [%c] (%t:%x) %m%n"/> -->
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <!-- ============================== -->
    <!-- Append messages to the console -->
    <!-- ============================== -->

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Threshold" value="DEBUG" />
        <param name="Target" value="System.out" />

        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <!-- The default pattern: Date Priority [Category] Message\n -->
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <logger name="org.apache">
        <level value="WARN" />
    </logger>


    <!-- ======================= -->
    <!-- Setup the Root category -->
    <!-- ======================= -->
    <root>
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILEZEUS" />
    </root>


</log4j:configuration>
```

Answer (score -2):

Question is still unclear but If you want to load any file from resources then this code will help you.

```
import java.io.InputStream;

public final class ResourceLoader {

public static  InputStream load(String fileName){

    InputStream input = ResourceLoader.class.getResourceAsStream(fileName);

      if(input==null){
        input = ResourceLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("/"+fileName);
     }
    return input;   
   }
}
```

Comment: I have multiple project dependecies and of those is inserting a log4j configuration file insede to my final jar, and subscribring my resource jar. Log4j automatically reads the log4j.xml(or properties) file doesnt not need to read a resource file

Comment: But in the last line you wrote to get log4jproperties file from resource folder